# How to display a single image using JS/JQ from a query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Using Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

The below code runs a query, which has multiple results. It then iterates through these and displays.

```
profileURL: Badgeresults[i].get('SentTo').get('pic'),
```

returns a profile picture, which I only want to show once, currently because I have it under the

```
 `_.each(Badges, function (item) {`
```

section it repeats for each object returned.

Where and how can I add a line to display the profile picture only once, I know it needs to be outside of      `_.each(Badges, function (item) {`  but I want it to appear at the top of these results. I presume I need to use something like `$('#profile_pic').attr('src',imageURLs[0]);

to display it?`

-

```
            query.find({
                success: function(Badgeresults) {
                    // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's

                    var Badges = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < Badgeresults.length; i++) {

                            Badges.push({

                        imageURL: Badgeresults[i].get('Global_Badges_img'),
                        categorySelected: Badgeresults[i].get('category'),
                        badgeNameSelected: Badgeresults[i].get('BadgeName'),
                        AwardedBy: Badgeresults[i].get('uploadedBy').get('username'),
                        AwardedTo: Badgeresults[i].get('SentTo').get('username'),
                        profileURL: Badgeresults[i].get('SentTo').get('pic'),
                        comment: Badgeresults[i].get('Comment'),



                    });

                }

_.each(Badges, function (item) {
                    var wrapper = $('<div></div>');
                    //$('#profile_pic').append('<img class="images BadgeImgOutline responsive-image"  src="' + item.profileURL + '" />');
                    //wrapper.append('<img class="images responsive-image BadgeImgOutline" src="' + item.profileURL + '" />'+ '<br>');
                    wrapper.append('<img class="images responsive-image BadgeImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />'+ '<br>');
                    wrapper.append('<div class="tag categorySelectedlabel">' + item.categorySelected  + '</div>' + '<br>');
                    wrapper.append('<div class="tag badgeNameSelected">' + item.badgeNameSelected   + '</div>' + '<br>');
                    wrapper.append('<div class="tag awardedbylabel">' + item.AwardedBy   + '</div>' + '<br>');
                    wrapper.append('<div class="tag senttolabel">' + item.AwardedTo   + '</div>' + '<br>');
                    wrapper.append('<div class="item  fui-chat">' + ' Reason: ' + item.comment + '</div>' + '<br>');  



                        $('#containerFriendsBadges').append(wrapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

"display the profile picture only once" - does that mean that Badgeresults (or your Badges) can contain same picture (url) many times?

If so - I would just write a check for duplicate strings before putting them into Badges and place it (the check) before  Badges.push({..

Comment: yes it does. Not sure I can really accept the answer, Its not detailed enough

Comment: OK, sure, I understand :) If you can provide whole code (jsfiddle for ex.) I would gladly be more specific :)